# When i tried to create new react project list of errors showed in my terminnal

Tags: reactjs, npx

I used `npx create-react-app myfirstapp` command to create new project in react, then list of errors showed in a terminal. I was confused about those errors.
[image]

This is the error that I have been showed. How can I fix those errors?

Comment: Looks like some other process is accessing the same resource and receiving permission denied. Go to task manager in windows and try to kill all the nodejs process. Try again.